# Reverse Engineering GUI programs

Tags: ida, ghidra

I am trying to reverse a 32-bit Win32 GUI application. It was compiled using Visual C++ 6.0 and uses the Win32 API. I am trying to figure out what happens when I click any particular button in the application. The problem is, whenever I stop execution using a debugger (x32dbg) execution is in a Win32 DLL file, not in an application function.

Any suggestions on how to tackle this? How do I determine what happens when I click any particular button?

Thank you

Comment: First you should spend some time understanding the Win32 **message loop** and the fact that GetMessage() is, in contrast to PeekMessage(), a *blocking* call which will not return until it has an event to deliver.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage.  You probably want to breakpoint the instruction following GetMessage() or whatever mechanism is being used.